How do I prevent ink bleeding on thin crepe paper while making drawings?

Crepe paper is a thin crafting paper made from tissue paper covered with a glue-like substance. This makes crepe paper hard and stiff. Crepe paper is also fire-resistant. Some crepe paper projects are: paper flowers, applique, tassels and garlands, pinatas.
Source

How do I prevent ink bleeding on thin crepe paper while making drawings?

What are you doing with the ink? Drawings to see later? Marking out for cutting? One issue I've seen with coloured crepe paper is its own dye bleeding if it gets damp

It could help us if you added a picture of how the bleeding looks for you. The definition you cite doesn't sound at all like the stuff I know as "crepe paper", so I'm not even sure which material you're having the problem with.

Tissue paper, crepe paper, even construction paper are going to absorb ink because they are much more porous than regular drawing/printing paper. Like a sponge, they are actually pulling more ink out of the pen than usual. So those papers are always going to bleed when using liquid ink. They are about using the paper's texture and color as is and are not made to support drawing materials.
If you want to draw on them anyway it would be best to try other drawing tools: soft leaded pencils, chalk pastels, oil pastels... Unfortunately crepe paper is also very weak and will tear easily. The only pen based tool that might work are paint/gel pens but even then you will have difficulty because that paper is really not made for drawing.
